# How to add spaces between string in a list that are in a lot of lists in a text file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add multiple lists into a text file, but all the strings inside are closed together when I try this method. My goal is to separate the strings inside.

```
checkingB = [['MARKETING', 'FCL10043', 'Ms_AUNG_SAN_LWIN', '21st_JULY', '1234'], 
['MARKETING', 'FCL10043', 'Ms_AUNG_SAN_LWIN', '21st_JULY', '102761697'], 
['PHYSICS', 'FCL10005', 'Ms_SHELLA_GEORGINA_BEATRICE', '15th_JULY', '102761697']]

with open('subjects.txt', 'a') as delA:
    for e in checkingB:
        delA.writelines(e)
        delA.writelines(' ')
        delA.write('\n')
```

- Expected output in the text file:

  MARKETING FCL10043 Ms_AUNG_SAN_LWIN 21st_JULY 1234
  MARKETING FCL10043 Ms_AUNG_SAN_LWIN 21st_JULY 102761697

  PHYSICS FCL10005 Ms_SHELLA_GEORGINA_BEATRICE 15th_JULY 102761697
- Real output:

  MARKETINGFCL10043Ms_AUNG_SAN_LWIN21st_JULY1234
  MARKETINGFCL10043Ms_AUNG_SAN_LWIN21st_JULY102761697

  PHYSICSFCL10005Ms_SHELLA_GEORGINA_BEATRICE15th_JULY102761697

Comment: If you want to add spaces, you might want to use `join()` plus `write` instead of `writelines()`

Comment: Try `'\n'.join([' '.join(l) for l in checkingB])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
with open('subjects.txt', 'a') as f:
    for row in checkingB:
        f.write(' '.join(row)+'\n')
```